# How can I center the align-environment in a itemize environment?

Tags: math-mode, align, itemize

I need the align-environment to be centered in a itemize-environment. At the current state, the align-environment is not centered, it is on the right site of the itemize-environment. i couldnt find a solution of this problem in the internet. this is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} %Wissenschaftliche längere Arbeit, wie {report} aber als KOMA-Script-Klasse, was erweiterte Funktionen bietet
%================
%PAKETE
%================
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %führt bei der Kodierung Umlaute zu einem Zeichen zusammen
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Zur direkten Eingabe von Umlauten ohne Befehle wie \"a
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Lädt Trennmuster nach neuer deutscher Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{graphicx} %Einbindung von Grafikdateien
\usepackage{amsmath} %Erweiterer Mathemodus
\usepackage{amssymb} %-"-
\usepackage{textcomp} % für µ etc. in Textumgebung
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Zur Einrichtung von Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage{helvet} %Arial
\usepackage{wrapfig} %Für Textunmflossene Grafiken
\usepackage{siunitx} %Eingeben von SI-Einheiten in Textumgebungen
%\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx} %Stellt deutsche Ausgabe von SI-Einheiten für Textumgebung ein
\usepackage{hyperref} %Zum anzeigen von HTML-Links
%\usepackage{subfig} %Um mehrere Grafiken via {subfigure} in ein eine {figure}-Umgebung zu tun
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}%für koordinatensystem zeichnen
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}%fürs durchstreichen im mathemodus
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \underline{Schnittpunkt:}\\
    \begin{align*}
         g_1 &= g_2\\
         \vec{r}(t) &= \vec{r}(s)\\
         \vec{r}_1 + t\vec{a}_1 &= \vec{r}_2 + s\vec{a}_2\\
        \textrm{t und s sind die Unbekannten.}\\
    \end{align*}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Gibt es eine Lösung $t_S$ oder $s_S$, schneiden sich die Geraden.\\
        \item Gibt es keine Lösung, sind die Geraden entweder parallel oder windschief.\\
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: It is on the right because you have the bulky text `\textrm{t und s sind die Unbekannten.}` part of the align. And your example is unfortunately far from minimal, you are loading tons of packages that are not relevant to the question, I think.

Comment: hmm. okay i see, isnt there a way i can keep this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the text in the last line  of the environment. You can either write it as an intertext, or use the `\clap` command, which centres its argument w.r.t. the insertion point, while making it have 0 width. I took the liberty to use the vector arrows from `esvect` since you load this package.

Comment aside: you don't have to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`. The latter does it for you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} %Wissenschaftliche längere Arbeit, wie {report} aber als KOMA-Script-Klasse, was erweiterte Funktionen bietet
%================
%PAKETE
%================
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %führt bei der Kodierung Umlaute zu einem Zeichen zusammen
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Zur direkten Eingabe von Umlauten ohne Befehle wie \"a
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Lädt Trennmuster nach neuer deutscher Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{graphicx} %Einbindung von Grafikdateien
\usepackage{amsmath} %Erweiterer Mathemodus
\usepackage{amssymb} %-"-
\usepackage{textcomp} % für µ etc. in Textumgebung
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Zur Einrichtung von Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage{helvet} %Arial
\usepackage{wrapfig} %Für Textunmflossene Grafiken
\usepackage{siunitx} %Eingeben von SI-Einheiten in Textumgebungen
%\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx} %Stellt deutsche Ausgabe von SI-Einheiten für Textumgebung ein
\usepackage{hyperref} %Zum anzeigen von HTML-Links
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}%für koordinatensystem zeichnen
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}%fürs durchstreichen im mathemodus
\usepackage[b]{esvect}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \underline{Schnittpunkt:}
    \begin{align*}
         g_1 &= g_2\\
         \vv{r}(t) &= \vv{r}(s)\\
         \vv*{r}{1} + t\vv*{a}{1} &= \vv*{r}{2} + s\vv*{a}{2}\\[-1.5ex]
        \intertext{t und s sind die Unbekannten.}
    \end{align*}
    \begin{align*}
         g_1 &= g_2\\
         \vv{r}(t) &= \vv{r}(s)\\
         \vv*{r}{1} + t\vv*{a}{1} &= \vv*{r}{2} + s\vv*{a}{2} \\
        \clap{$t$ und $s$ sind die Unbekannten.}
    \end{align*}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Gibt es eine Lösung $t_S$ oder $s_S$, schneiden sich die Geraden.
        \item Gibt es keine Lösung, sind die Geraden entweder parallel oder windschief.
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} %Wissenschaftliche längere Arbeit, wie {report} aber als KOMA-Script-Klasse, was erweiterte Funktionen bietet
%================
%PAKETE
%================
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %führt bei der Kodierung Umlaute zu einem Zeichen zusammen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Zur direkten Eingabe von Umlauten ohne Befehle wie \"a
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Lädt Trennmuster nach neuer deutscher Rechtschreibung
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \underline{Schnittpunkt:}\\
    \begin{align*}
         g_1 &= g_2\\
         \vec{r}(t) &= \vec{r}(s)\\
         \vec{r}_1 + t\vec{a}_1 &= \vec{r}_2 + s\vec{a}_2\\
        \text{$t$ und $s$ sind die}&\text{ Unbekannten.}\\
    \end{align*}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Gibt es eine Lösung $t_S$ oder $s_S$, schneiden sich die Geraden.\\
        \item Gibt es keine Lösung, sind die Geraden entweder parallel oder windschief.\\
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(My settings have problems with the umlaute but they should be fine on your machine.)